# Inserting node field value programmatically in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, nodes

I'm trying to insert values for a node field from a custom module. The value will only be inserted from that module and then no operation for that node will be performed, so hook is not in my consideration. I've tried to directly insert values to the field_data_... and field_revision_... tables. but I've found that drupal also saves the values (serialized) in field_config and field_config_instance tables as blob. since I'm only inserting values in two tables drupal is not reading values I've inserted for nodes. I couldn't understand the serialization stored in DB. so I'm searching for a method that will help me to insert values through API or any other neat way.

any help on the thing I'm trying to accomplish would be great. Thank you

EDIT:
after taking look at serialized content of field_config table I understood that the serialized data is just field configuration and get inserted into the table on first save. My problem solved by saving the first value through admin/content and now my direct DB inserted data is available to the node. this is the serialized data I've got:

```
a:7:
   {s:12:"translatable";
    s:1:"0";
    s:12:"entity_types";
    a:0:{}
    s:8:"settings";
    a:3:
       {s:9:"precision";
        s:2:"10";s:5:"scale";
        s:1:"2";
        s:17:"decimal_separator";
        s:1:",";
       }
    s:7:"storage";
    a:5:
       {s:4:"type";
        s:17:"field_sql_storage";
        s:8:"settings";
        a:0:{}
        s:6:"module";
        s:17:"field_sql_storage";
        s:6:"active";
        s:1:"1";
        s:7:"details";
        a:1:
           {s:3:"sql";
            a:2:
               {s:18:"FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT";
                a:1:
                   {s:22:"field_data_field_total";
                    a:1:
                       {s:5:"value";
                        s:17:"field_total_value";
                       }
                   }
                s:19:"FIELD_LOAD_REVISION";
                a:1:
                   {s:26:"field_revision_field_total";
                    a:1:
                       {s:5:"value";
                        s:17:"field_total_value";
                       }
                   }
               }
          }
     }
     s:12:"foreign keys";
     a:0:{}
     s:7:"indexes";
     a:0:{}
     s:2:"id";
     s:2:"34";
    }
```

Comment: just direct DB insert as I've mentioned in post, nothing else.

Comment: Have you got any code we can look at?

Comment: Actually the problem is solved. I've edited the post and gave details of it. Thank you SpaceBeers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```php
$node = new stdClass();
$node->uid = 1;
$node->name = 'admin';
$node->type = 'page';
$node->language = 'und';
$node->title = 'Your title';
$node->status = 1;
$node->promote = 0;
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->created = timestamp;
$node->field_description = array(
    'und' => array(
        array(
            'value' => 'asdasd'
        )
    )
);
$node->nid = 1; // define nid if you wish to update existing node
// if you wouldn't define $node->nid then new node would be created,
// otherwise node would be updated with you data provided for all
// fields which you'll list here.

...
// other node's fields

node_save_action($node);
```

Comment: You should better use the `LANGUAGE_NONE` constant instead of the language string `'und'`.

Comment: Yes, it's probably so. But it's just an example ... if you'd have multilingual site then you'd use `'en'`, `'fr'` or whatever.